# Creating Task Manager's like Graphs

Tags: c#, .net, graph, diagram

Is anyone aware of a way to create graphs like Task Manager's in C#, that represent
real-time performance data?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Buy a 3rd party component library (like ChartFX or some such), or roll your own using either WPF or for Windows Forms by drawing to a canvas region using the Graphics class (System.Windows.Drawing afaicr).

Comment: No need to buy a chart library in the first run. Simply take [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c).

Comment: Asked the same question few weeks ago, no real answers were generated (3rd party controls are our of the question as they are overkill for the job) - ended up drawing it myself...

Answer (score 1):

For the reference, [Advanced Microsoft Chart Control for .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c17257/Advanced-Microsoft-Chart-Control-for-NET-Framework-35.htm) article has an example how to achieve effect of the scrolling X axis to the left in time (on the each tick of the timer).

Answer (score 0):

You can download MSChart sample on http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart.

build WinSample
then you can see sample in "Content -> Working with Data -> Real Time Data -> Real Time Data (Timer or Thread Safe)" menu